# Swift Package Manager - Dependency on active branch doesn’t pull new commits

Tags: swift, dependencies, swift-package-manager

I'm writing a Swift Package that relies on another package that I manage ([Netswift](https://github.com/MrSkwiggs/Netswift/tree/bleeding_edge)). I've setup a `bleeding_edge` branch there, where I commit every few hours (i.e when I notice access control is wrong, or any other minor edit).

Now my current package has a dependency on the github repo for Netswift, with that `bleeding_edge` branch, as pictured below:

```
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/MrSkwiggs/Netswift", .branch("bleeding_edge")),
]
```

Unfortunately, resolving the dependency graph by any of the following means (updating `Package.swift` with an empty space somewhere, running `swift package update`) does not pull new commits from that branch.

The only way I found to force-update is to specify a different branch, resolve dependency graph, then revert back to the branch I actually need, then resolve dependency graph again.

Is there a better way to force-update the dependency graph?

I also don't want to add a target with an absolute path to this other local package, as colleagues will also need to rely on this at some point in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use XCode's built-in package update functionality, which can be found under:

`File -> Swift Packages -> Update to Latest Package Versions`

Running `swift package update` only works when the package is being worked on as a standalone; if the package is being edited through an existing XCode project/workspace then you need to let XCode handle it.

Comment: Is there an automatic way to have Xcode update the latest commits when the VCS root changes (branch, merge etc). Or do we need to keep manually updating even in this case.

Comment: @ZeMoon Usually XCode is smart enough to detect changes to the dependencies and resolves them automatically. If you're indeed using a branch dependency, you may still need to manually ask it to update the dependencies, as it caches each install and uses that whenever possible.